# stream insertion operator cascade reference to object

Tags: c++, ostream

Why is it necessary that function below should have a reference to ostream object. 
I didnt properly understood it deeply and could not find it anywhere regarding stream insertion operator, function that returns reference to the object,

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& osObject, const class& cObject)
```

I known about friends and all this stuff but just about this reference to object, i read related to it that this is used because we can do something like this

```
cout<<obj1<<obj2<<....<<....<<....
```

so goes on, but didnt properly understood it in detail. I would be very glad if some one would help me out. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator is a function. The function has two arguments. One is the stream to perform the streaming on, and the other is the class to stream. When you write `a << b`, a `operator<<` function is automatically called with arguments `a` and `b`.